# OpenCV detectMultiScale() error in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

So I was trying to learn how to do facial recognition using OpenCV v3.0. Now after confirming that the camera can actually runs and that my XML files load. I began by uncommenting the code line by line until I found the error in line 64.

```
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
```

Running that line will give me the following error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x63E6DF62 (msvcp120d.dll) in ConsoleApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000003D.
```

Now I have already tried using the haarcascades and haarcascadesCUDA, but to no avail. I am including the code below as any help would be appreciated to understadning what is causing the program to crash here.

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
/* Function Headers */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame );
/* Global variables */
String face_cascade_name = "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml";
String eyes_cascade_name = "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml";
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
CascadeClassifier eyes_cascade;
String window_name = "Capture - Face detection";
/* @function main */
int main( void )
{
    VideoCapture capture (0);
    Mat frame;
    //-- 1. Load the cascades
    if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading face cascade\n"); return -1; };
    if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading eyes cascade\n"); return -1; };
    //-- 2. Read the video stream
    if ( ! capture.isOpened() ) { printf("--(!)Error opening video capture\n"); return -1; }
    while (  capture.read(frame) )
    {
        if( frame.empty() )
        {
            printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
            break;
        }
        //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
        detectAndDisplay( frame );
        int c = waitKey(10);
        if( (char)c == 27 ) { break; } // escape
    }
    return 0;
}
/* @function detectAndDisplay */
void detectAndDisplay( Mat frame )
{
    std::vector<Rect> faces;
    Mat frame_gray;
    cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );
    //-- Detect faces
    face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
    for( size_t i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
    {
        Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width/2, faces[i].y + faces[i].height/2 );
        ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width/2, faces[i].height/2), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        Mat faceROI = frame_gray( faces[i] );
        std::vector<Rect> eyes;
        //-- In each face, detect eyes
        eyes_cascade.detectMultiScale( faceROI, eyes, 1.1, 2, 0 |CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );
        for( size_t j = 0; j < eyes.size(); j++ )
        {
            Point eye_center( faces[i].x + eyes[j].x + eyes[j].width/2, faces[i].y + eyes[j].y + eyes[j].height/2 );
            int radius = cvRound( (eyes[j].width + eyes[j].height)*0.25 );
            circle( frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        }
    }
    //-- Show what you got
    imshow( window_name, frame );
}
```

Perhaps the parameter is being misused or there is another issue. Anyway thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you using visual studio 2013?

Comment: does your started program have access to the opencv_objdetect dll file?

Comment: can you try to remove CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE flag? haar cascades use integral images and therefore dont scale the image but scale the box sizes

Comment: Actually yes I am currently using VS 2013, would that present a problem? I also tried deleting the flag. As for the objdetect I will search for that right now.

Comment: Ok I just checked I already linked all my dll files including that one.

Comment: You need to link to the _-lib_ files, and put the dll into your exe folder, or add the dll folder to PATH. Can you run in debug and post the error message?

Comment: Ok well I already linked the lib files although I have 2 lib folders the staticlib and lib. I added the lib folder. As for the dll they are already with my exe.

Comment: Have you solved this issue already?

Comment: No but I noticed that this only happens in laptops I ended up using Python instead of c++ to make it work

Comment: I have the same problem but with VS2015.

Comment: The only way I found to be able to solve the problem on C++ with laptops was to use an external Webcam.

Answer (score 0):

I started out with the same tutorial and had the same exception arising from detectMultiScale call. I keyed in the correct full path for the haar xml files from the opencv installation directory and that resolved the issue.